# How do i check what symbol is currently open on the chart?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i am trying to implement different behaviors of the script depending on the current symbol that is opened, how do i check the name of the symbol?

for example (pseudocode):

if the symbol is CADJPY - do this

else if the symbol is NAS100USD - do this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `syminfo.ticker` to get the symbol name without exchange prefix e.g. `MSFT`, or `syminfo.tickerid` to get the symbol name with exchange prefix e.g. `NASDAQ:MSFT`.

Comment: does both methods return a string?

so using the syminfo.ticker would be this way (example):

symbol = syminfo.ticker

if symbol == "EURUSD"
    //do this

else if symbol == "NAS100USD"
    // do this

Comment: Both return `simple string`.